# Avoiding Translation Look aside buffer ( TLB ) pollution when mmap()

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, intel, micro-optimization, tlb

When we want to write a data item, the block containing the data is brought into the cache first and data item is written into the cache. This can cause cache pollution. To avoid this, Intel has introduced no temporal instructions.

If I'm going to be using mmap() to write data to the file and never going to read again, is it possible to avoid TLB entry creation for this ? Is there anything instruction similar to non temporal instructions available ?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there isn't, since you can't use hugepages for file-backed mappings.  Using `write` with a buffer size of maybe 1/2 L2 cache size or something like that might actually perform better; you should test.  (Although the kernel prob. won't use NT stores when copying your buffer to the pagecache).  You can avoid pagecache pollution if the file data is *really* not going to be referenced for a long time by using `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` to encourage the kernel to drop it from RAM after writing it to disk.

Comment: pwrite() may be more appropriate than write() depending on your access patterns. But yes, you should definitely test. Another suggestion is to try to ensure that all of the file modifications happen on the same CPU to mitigate the pollution. Also don't forget to measure the cost of any final TLB shootdown when the file is unmapped.

Answer (score 2):

TLB entries are needed by the CPU to map from the virtual address to the physical address, so it is not possible to avoid them with `mmap()` or any similar API.

Even if it were possible to avoid storing the mapping in the TLB, *every* access to the mapped memory would need to reload the corresponding entries from the page tables, so the performance would be much worse.
Non-temporal accesses make sense only for *stores*, but the page table entries are *read*.

Comment: You could imagine a non-temporal hint for TLB entries, so maybe they'd be evicted sooner, or only ever stay in the L1 TLB instead of moving to the L2 TLB when evicted from L1 DTLB.  This would be analogous to PREFETCHNTA only bringing data into L1, without polluting the larger L2.  There's no mechanism for anything like this with TLB entries on x86, but not because it's impossible to do anything with a non-temporal hint for loads.  (Good point that TLB entries cache loads, not stores, though).